# Not able to set the state of array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to find the social media platform when user is typing the comma separated string. I am iterating over each comma separated string and checking that whether it includes any on the predefined string of array. It is working correctly but when I tried to set the state it is not able to do the same.

```
var social=["FACEBOOK","INSTAGRAM","PINTEREST","SINA","YOU","QUORA","GOOGLE","GITLAB",
                    "GITHUB","BLOGGER","MEDIUM","REDDIT","TWITTER","HACKERRANK","HACKEREARTH"]
        var socStr=e.target.value;
        var local=[];
        socStr=socStr.split(",");
        for(i=0;i<socStr.length;i++){
            for(j=0;j<social.length;j++){
                if(socStr[i].toUpperCase().includes(social[j])){
                    local=local.concat(social[j]);
                    console.log(local);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(i===socStr.length-1){
                this.setState({
                    data:{
                        ...this.state.data,
                        socArr:local
                    }
                },()=>console.log(this.state.data.socArr))
            }
        }
```

it correctly printing the value of local array but its value is not setting to state variable socArr.

Comment: So then that means `i === socStr.length - 1` is not being met...

Comment: It is printing the value of socArr in callback but it is empty array even when local array has some element in it.

Answer (score 0):

I have refactored your code a bit for better readability. The code below is working fine for me:

```
onValueChanged() {
 var inputValue = 'facebook,reddit,aa';
 var local = [];
 var splittedInput = inputValue.split(',');

 for (var entry of splittedInput) {
  var result = social.find(function(s) {
   return entry.toUpperCase().includes(s);
  });

  if (result) {
   local.push(result);
  }
 }

 console.log(local);

 this.setState({
  data: {
   socArr: local
  }
 }, () => console.log(this.state.data.socArr))
}
```